# AtomicInteger thread safety

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomicinteger

How can I achieve that the while loop here is always executed exactly 100 times. When I execute the code, in rare cases it prints 99 or 98 lines on the console and not always 100, which I do not understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Print implements Runnable {
    static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() < 100)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            threads.add(new Thread(new Print()));

        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();

        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: This code should work because `getAndIncrement` is thread-safe, are you sure it prints only 98 or 99 times?

Comment: Thanks Karol. Could the IDE or other programs running in the background be affecting the output? I tried to reproduce the problem but was unable to. I had copied the console output in Excel and I am sure that it was once 98 and the other 99 lines.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem and the code looks correct, I don't know how you could have received 98 or 99 instead of 100.

Comment: The counting part looks ok to me.  I have a tiny smidgen of doubt about the parallel println calls; the [description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) suggests that printing the value and printing the line terminator are distinct actions, which I suppose *may* result in two values followed by two newlines - but then you'd have obviously-wrong output.

Comment: I agree with @iggy, this is likely an artefact with `println`. To confirm, try incrementing another `AtomicInteger` in the body of the `if` statement and observe its final value.

Comment: [ExecutorCompletionService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) ..since java 1.5!;)

Answer (score 2):

Unable to replicate your reported experience.

In my mind’s debugger, that seems correct as I cannot see any thread-safety fault in your code.

To automate further testing, I altered your code as follows. Rather than call `System.out.println`, I added the thread ID to a `List` of `Long`. I made the list a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for thread-safety. I can programmatically detect if the resulting list is not exactly 100 elements in size.

```java
package work.basil.demo;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Print implements Runnable
{
    static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger( 0 );
    static CopyOnWriteArrayList < Long > list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList <>();

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        while ( atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() < 100 )
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
            list.add( Thread.currentThread().getId() );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - demo starting. " + Instant.now() );
        for ( int cycle = 0 ; cycle < 1_000_000 ; cycle++ )
        {
            ArrayList < Thread > threads = new ArrayList <>();

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
                threads.add( new Thread( new Print() ) );

            for ( Thread thread : threads )
                thread.start();

            for ( Thread thread : threads )
                thread.join();

//            System.out.println( "list.size() = " + list.size() );
//            if ( list.size() == 100 ) { System.out.println( "DEBUG list.size() = " + ( list.size() ) ); }
            if ( list.size() != 100 ) { System.out.println( "DEBUG list.size() = " + ( list.size() ) ); }
        }
        System.out.println( "INFO - demo done. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run on a Mac mini (2018) 3 GHz Intel Core i5 with six real cores and no hyper-threading, and 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, using Java 16 within IntelliJ. Running `cycle` to a million takes about 5 minutes.

```
INFO - demo starting. 2021-06-08T22:11:56.010181Z
INFO - demo done. 2021-06-08T22:16:26.982616Z
```

### `ExecutorService`

By the way, in modern Java we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. Instead, use the [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework added to Java 5.

Here is revised version of the code above, rejiggered to use an executor service.

```java
public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println( "INFO - demo starting. " + Instant.now() );
    for ( int cycle = 0 ; cycle < 1_000_000 ; cycle++ )
    {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 );

        int countTasks = 5;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < countTasks ; i++ )
        {
            executorService.submit( new Print2() );
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination( Duration.ofMinutes( 7 ).toSeconds() , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

//            System.out.println( "list.size() = " + list.size() );
//            if ( list.size() == 100 ) { System.out.println( "DEBUG list.size() = " + ( list.size() ) ); }
        if ( list.size() != 100 ) { System.out.println( "DEBUG list.size() = " + ( list.size() ) ); }
    }
    System.out.println( "INFO - demo done. " + Instant.now() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
    static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0); change to
    AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);// 0->1 no static
  
    while (atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() < 100) //change to:
    while (atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() != 101)//100->101
```

remove "static" for the variable atomicInteger.
if you need to get exactly 1...100 (not 0...99) set the atomic value to 1 and in the loop set !=101
my print
https://gyazo.com/6762c78ae44c0b06d05e316768114167

The comment clarified the question: the key point is the use of statics. use a semaphore

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class Print implements Runnable {
    static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(1);

    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public Print(final Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            while ((count = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()) != 101) {
            System.out.println(
            "COUNT::" + count + "::" + Thread.currentThread());
        }
           atomicInteger.set(1);
            
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            threads.add(new Thread(new Print(semaphore)));
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();
        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work correctly, if thread 1 arrives and increments to 101 (and receive 100), thread 2 can arrive and increment to 102 (and receive 101), and so on for threads 3 - 5.

Comment: Please remove the word "static for the variable atomicInteger. This is my print for 3threads and while !=5 gyazo.com/bb8a712e1d32934c362e1a662d0b3a80

Comment: The use static is required for the problem the OP tries to implement (or they would need to pass a single instance of the `AtomicInteger` to each instance of `Print`), as the shared use of the `AtomicInteger` is the whole point.

Comment: I supplemented the answer if static is important in the context of this question