# Thread safety if loop is thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomicinteger

The while loop in this question is thread safe: [AtomicInteger thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885351/atomicinteger-thread-safety). If I insert the randomSum method in the thread safe while loop, is the code still thread safe? Or should the randomSum method be synchronized?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Print implements Runnable {
    static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static Random random = new Random(1);

    public static int randomSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += random.nextInt();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (atomicInteger.getAndIncrement() < 100)
            System.out.println(randomSum() + " " + Thread.currentThread());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            threads.add(new Thread(new Print()));

        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.start();

        for (Thread thread : threads)
            thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, still thread-safe. No need to synchronize this `randomSum` method since you haven't modify any value outside the method.

Comment: @Sachith Dickwella Well - actually `random.nextInt` modifies random internally, but Random is thread safe.

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819638, but if `Random` is thread-safe, then it follows that your `randomSum` method is thread-safe, since `sum` and `i` are local variables and therefore thread-confined.

Answer (score 6):

The method `randomSum` is thread-safe, as is its use.

The only shared object is `random`. The Java API documentation states that instances of `java.util.Random` are thread-safe but may encounter performance issues if used concurrently (presumably due to synchronization) and that [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) should be considered instead if performance is an issue.